# Find the percent of boys and girls

Tags: average, percentages

I have a basic school academic question which despite of trying **very** hard I was unable to find a solution -

**Average score of girls is an exam is $67$ and that of boys is $62$. Find the percentage of girls and boys?**

I think the question is incomplete - cause average is nothing but addition of each student marks divided by total number of student - and I was never able to find the solution - is my understanding correct - does an answer exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You need another piece of information - the overall average with boys and girls taken together. You can see that by constructing some examples.

If 80% of the students are girls then the overall average will be 66: 80% of the way from 62 to 67. If 80% are boys it will be 63.

You should be able to see how to work backwards from the overall average to the percentage of boys.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The question is incomplete. Some more information is needed to solve the question.